# Exception on excuteUpdate

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I am getting an exception as

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: String or binary data would be truncated.
```

The exception is thrown at the following line:

```
PrepareStmt.setBinaryStream(1, new ByteArrayInputStream(data), data.length);  
updatePrepareStmt.executeUpdate();
```

I am using MS-SQL db. Can anyone help me solve this problem?

The datatype of the column in which I am trying to insert data is varbinary and the length of the data is also not large. I am just inserting "test".

**UPDATE**
Now I have increased the size of datatype varbinary. Made it to 1024, but I get new Exception now :-

> com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:The
>   conversion from varbinary to BLOB is
>   unsupported

Can anyone comment on this Exception?

Comment: _On executeUpdate, I get this exception_ … Very poetic!

Comment: What is the datatype of the field in which you are trying to insert the data ?

Comment: The datatype of the column in which I am trying to insert data is varbinary

Comment: You are entering the data which doesn't fit with the size of column. increase the size of column in DB or compress your data

Comment: About your update, `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:The conversion from varbinary to BLOB is unsupported`. With a previous version of Oracle, I have had to run an `Insert` query in my table (which create the BLOB first), and then I was able to write in it after a `Select`...

Answer (score 3):

As the exception message sais, your data seems to be larger than the database field it should be written to. What is the maximum of `data.length` and what's the maximum length of your column?

Comment: The datatype of the column in which I am trying to insert data is varbinary and the length of the data is also not large. I am just inserting "test"

Comment: Could you show the full prepared statement? If might be another column that is overflowing.

Comment: private PreparedStatement updatePrepareStmt;  updatePrepareStmt = dbConn.getConnection().prepareStatement(s);

Answer (score 0):

Increase the column capacity.. if it is `varchar(20)` make it `varchar(200)` or something that can accomodate your data.